# Nginx: how to do rewrite？

Tags: apache, web, nginx

My website have three different pages:

```
www.abc.com/
www.abc.com/node
www.abc.com/memeber
```

If I type `www.abc.com` in the browser,it goes to `www.abc.com/`, how can I change it to `www.abc.com/node` when I type `www.abc.com` and keep the `www.abc.com/memeber` normal as usual?

Comment: You want the root url `www.abc.com` to **redirect** to `/node` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes,but cloud visit www.abc.com/memeber as usual.

Comment: My problem sloved! Thx evevyone!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a small note, use `return` instead of `rewrite` for redirects, [check nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites)

```
location = / {
  return 301 $scheme://$server_name/node
}
location / {
  # normal location handling, using try_files for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me provided I was only serving static files.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.abc.com;
    root /var/www/abc;

    if ($request_uri = '/') {
        rewrite ^ /node break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location = / {
  rewrite ^ /node;
}
```